# Влияние ORDER BY на скорость выполнения запроса

Tags: mysql

Допустим, есть 1,000,000 записей в таблице. Мне нужно найти запись 999,999.
Будет ли `ORDER BY` влиять на скорость выборки?
На работе мне говорят, что при `ORDER BY ASC` запросу придётся обработать строки от 0 до 999,999, а если `DESC`, то только от 1,000,000 до 999,999, то есть одну строку.

Comment: Так вы бы взяли и проверили/протестировали это утверждение. А вообще - да, различие в скорости выполнения действительно большое выходит.

Comment: найти запись как ? оставить только ее с помощью limit - тогда да, записи должны быть сначала отсортированы а потом пропущено столько сколько указано. И еще вопрос как будет выполняться сортировка, может есть индекс и можно быстро пройтись по нему не поднимая основные данные. И собственно сама сортировка съест львиную долю времени, т.к. если индекса нет что бы понять что данная запись первая все равно надо пересмотреть все остальные что бы понять что они все должны быть за ней

Comment: @Mike но всё равно запрос `SELECT * FROM ChatMessages ORDER BY text ASC LIMIT 125551, 10` у меня выполняется за 650-800мс, а `SELECT * FROM ChatMessages ORDER BY text DESC LIMIT 0, 10` - за 150-190мс. Индексы в обоих запросах не используются.

Comment: @Regent А я и не говорил, что они будут одинаковы по времени. Собственно я начал фразу с того, что потребуется что то пропустить. И понятно что пропуск занимает время

Comment: @Mike получается, что на сортировку всех записей в таблице по полю, которое не находится в индексе, уходит около 150мс, а на пропуск 125551 записей в уже отсортированных данных - с добрых 500мс. Как-то это странно, на мой взгляд, получается. Надо будет почитать что-нибудь по этому поводу: когда я начал это использовать в коде, то особо не задумывался почему это в разы быстрее работает.

Comment: @Regent Видимо оно умеет не полностью сортировать. для поиска 10 первых в общем то достаточно выделить буфер на 10 записей и сверять очередную запись с последней из этого буфера. и если она меньше то находить куда ее вставить и выталкивать последнюю.

Comment: @Regent Протестировал и разницы не заметил,в обоих случаях пробегает одинаковое кол-во строк

Comment: @quaresma89 про количество проверяемых строк я и ничего не утверждал. Говорил лишь про скорость выполнения, и факт в том, что у меня `ASC LIMIT 125551, 10` выполняется в несколько раз дольше, чем `DESC LIMIT 0, 10`. При этом в обоих случаях ведь нужно просканировать таблицу целиком, чтобы отсортировать значения поля `text`, которое не входит ни в один из индексов таблицы. На практике у меня сортировка в этой таблице идёт по `id`, но даже в этом случае (сортировка по `PRIMARY KEY`) разница в скорости существенна. Объяснить это с точки зрения теории, к сожалению, не могу.

Comment: @quaresma89 То как именно выполняется конкретный запрос зависит от структуры таблицы, списка выбираемых колонок, наличия индексов и даже от того какие именно там данные. Однозначно ответить на ваш вопрос невозможно. Можно только рассматривать конкретный случай. А для этого надо знать эту самую структуру, все индексы на таблице и видеть план выполнения. Ничего из вышеперечисленного вы в вопросе не привели

Answer (score 0):

Направление сортировки ни на что не влияет. Разницы никакой нет: брать числа из конца или из начала. Но если вы делаете выборку `LIMIT 125551, 10`, и если там будут дополнительные условия (или как у вас нет индексов), mysql будет выбирать и сортировать 125551 строк и из них отбирать последние.

Касаемо отсутствия индексов - не факт что они не закешировались, даже если их нет.